# Could not find an option to pass parameter `CallerReference` in Terraform resource `aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

We are in the way to migrate from api calls to terraform to spin resources/accesses/policies in aws. I was bit struct in a place where I could not find an option to pass `CallerReference` to aws terraform resource `aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity`.

We have this option using api: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity.html

Do we have any custom options for passing the same in other ways?

Comment: Can you add your terraform code to the question above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not directly supported by TF, you can always use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) with AWS CLI to create your origin identity.